# Media Query Transition Text Bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

I'm using media queries on a website, and wanted to have it look a bit more natural/fluid, and so ive used    `*{transition:all 1s ease;}` to have the media queries "animate".  This works great on most elements in the site, except for text.  When re-sizing the text it jumps between several different sizes before landing on the correct one.  I've tested it in every modern browser, and it seems to only be happening in Google Chrome (not canary).  I thought that was a little strange.  Has anybody else had this problem? Is there any way to fix it?

Here's a gif of the re-sizing for better clarity: [image]

Comment: This is expected. The reason you are seeing it 'bounce' is because it is lagging through the various media queries.

Comment: Chris at css-tricks.com just did a big post about this : http://css-tricks.com/animated-media-queries/

Comment: You're right @JoshC, I just tried it on Google Chrome on a computer with a bit more ram and it transitions perfectly.

Comment: @RadicalEdward I actually ran into this a few days ago. Same scenario on my website... Should I put an answer..?

Comment: @Joshc Yeah, might as well.  More points at least.